# Formatting not retained in paste from Ditto (clipboard manager). Plain text pasted instead

Tags: clipboard, ditto

I'm trying to use Ditto on the Ditto documentation. If I were to copy the table of contents, then paste it (without Ditto) to the word processor, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pzo6.png,
and the formatting is maintained.

As as a result of the copy operation, the table of contents also goes into the Saved Items List (= History List = Lists the Clips saved from the Clipboard) in Ditto’s Main Window:

I open a blank document to paste from Ditto instead of the default clipboard, and press either Ctrl-`, the default Ditto window activation Global Hot Key, or click the tray icon.

From this point, I can do 3 things to close the Ditto window, and place the item on the clipboard (the default clipboard?).

1. Select the item, and press Enter
2. Put the cursor on the item, and double-click
3. Select the item, and press Ctrl-c

1) and 2) send a right-click where the cursor is, after the Ditto window closes (presumably to have the paste option ready to access?): Ctrl-c just closes the Ditto window.

Whichever method is used, the contents are pasted in what I believe is plain text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNYVf.png

How do I keep the formatting that the default clipboard keeps? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Table of Contents: -> Ditto - Configuration -> Options -> Supported Types
http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/Help/DittoConfig.htm#mb_SupportedTypes

I didn't know that you had to add supported types. There are much more to add: Supported types -> Add supported type
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxADM.png

I think these are the supported types for pasting(?) because after copying, Ditto detects the types that are in the clipboard, and you can add them to your supported types: Supported types -> Add supported type -> Currently on the clipboard

Since HTML can be detected, it's supported? But you actually have to add it to your list for it to be supported (for paste, or does it not even reach the clipboard?)? Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you have a problem with google doc, or any other source, copy what you need to copy, then open ditto option >> supported type >> click the add button >> click on "current clipboard type", you'll see the list of clipboard recognized by ditto from your copy. If you add all of them (or only the good one) it'll work.